# (Raspberry Pi) using python's sounddevice library doesn't..'sound' running my script from terminal why?

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi

as i said in Title i have a problem, hope you can help me....

i'm trying to play some wav files using sounddevice library from python 2.7 it took me a while to make it work and be able to use it, i am using it because i need to play some audio files with a bitdepth of 24bits (i'll get the DAC later).

So the problem i have is this. i am trying to run the most easy of the scripts and it is.. just playing a wav file like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import numpy
import scipy
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
import sounddevice as sd

fs,sound=scipy.io.wavfile.read('my.wav')
sd.play(sound,fs)
```

to check if it is working i did sudo python myscript.py... in terminal, but it didn`t sound or showed me an error in the script.  next i went to the python shell, ran it... and it sounded! .. i can understand why it doesn't sound when i try to use the terminal, and i need to use it because i also have to use GPIO

i would be thankful if you could help me.